# Reduce ttfb (time to first byte) website on cpanel magento

Tags: performance, magento, cpanel, performance-testing, network-protocols

I have tested my site freshdeals.co.in on http://www.webpagetest.org/result/150325_HZ_TAN/

I didn't understand why my site taking to much time in TTFB, and what i can do to reduce this.

Alos i would like to know for every http request on the page include this TTFB or not?

Answer (score 0):

I think your server is overloaded and due to that may be you are getting this issues, I will suggest you please monitor your server and optimize your MySQL and web server which is installed on your server.

Also, Please check page speed suggestion of your site and try to update it on your site : https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=freshdeals.co.in&tab=desktop

Comment: hey can give me any idea how to monitor server and optimize MySQL, i am using cpanel,

Comment: If you have root access, then you can monitor it through command line with "top" and "ps aufx" command

Answer (score 0):

How customized is the implementation?  Server capacity might be an issue but for a 15 second page load time it is more likely that a customization is the cause of the issue.  Excessive iteration is a fairly consistent problem for Magento implementations, often seen by many calls to Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::load().

Take the public dataset and load on a local computer and run a profiler against it.  XDebug or Zend Debugger both have profilers, or try New Relic.  If you aren't able to do that turn the query log on in MySQL and load a page.  In the worst case you should not see much more than 100 queries.  If you see more than that you will likely need to re-architect some customizations.

Also, make sure that you're using an opcache for PHP code and that your data cache is working.  But even if both of those are turned off you should not be seeing 15 second page load times.